# New to array variables - can I do this without a loop?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using VBA to import data from an Excel spreadsheet into an Access data base.  I have an array variable (data) set up with 17 elements and have the following code to import the 17 values from a single line of the spreadsheet:

```
For i = 1 To 17
    data(i) = Cells(Line.Row, i).Value
Next i
```

Can I do this without a loop?

BTW - I'm processing each line of the spreadsheet inside a loop as well, because different rows get different treatment based on the data in column 1.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid using a loop?

Comment: partly to learn, partly becuase I've always thought that loops were bad, partly to replace 3 lines with 1 if I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply assign the values of a Range to a variant variable, it will then hold the values in a 2-dimensional array.

You can use it like this: 
On the debug.print line, the first dimension refers to the row and is always 1 here.

```
Sub test()
    Dim v
    Dim line As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set line = Range("A2:Q2")
    v = line.Value

    ' accessing the values:
    For i = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
        Debug.Print v(1, i)
    Next

End Sub
```

As you say you are iterating over multiple lines as well, you can also assign the entire Range to `v` and iterate over both dimensions.

Comment: Thanks - I think using one array for both the inner and outer loop makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When passing `range` to any variable you could create an array. However, it would be 2 dimensional array. To make it one-dimensional we would need to transpose it (twice). So, the code could be as follow:

```
data = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(Line.Row, 1), _
                                                        Cells(Line.Row, 17))))
```

One more important information- this `data array` will start with index 1 instead of default 0.